# What of the "Sets, Classes, and Categories" approach to the foundations?

Tags: set-theory, category-theory, foundations

A 2001 [paper](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) by F.A. Muller proposes "ARC" (a modified form of [Ackermann set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory)) as a foundations of mathematics, and argues that it founds category theory more naturally and/or conveniently than other, competing approaches to set theory. Muller's approach looks interesting. I was wondering

- Has it gained many adherents?
- Has it been used as a basis for any foundational works since it was first proposed?
- Have any issues with ARC come to light in the past 12 years?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays people are getting very excited about an even better approach : the *Univalent Foundations Project* started by V.Voevodsky.

It is not only including Category Theory but also $\infty$-Category Theory.

In a very sketchy way, the aim is to replace the idea of *equality* by *homotopy* which is a more foundational concept.

For your questions :

-I am not able to say if ARC is getting famous or is having a lot of adhrents ; but I can tell you that the Univalent Foundations Project is getting famous and is having a lot of mathematicians working on it

-In 2013, it is clear that such a theory of Cathegory/Class/Set has to include $\infty$-Categories.

Comment: Can you briefly expand this idea with $\omega$-categories?

Comment: @user18921: Every equivalence relation generalizes equality. That is the whole point of equivalence relations.

Comment: The fact is that, this idea is developed by people that are already using $\infty$-Categories in their everyday life.
But defining properly $\infty$-Categories, or more generally $(\infty,n)$-Categories is a real pain in Set theory/Category theory.
On the contrary, if you have a theory of $\infty$-Categories, you have the notion of descrete $\infty$-Categories = Categories, and then the notion of Sets.